# Variables in pandas table are not updated during the cell running in Jupyter notebook: Problem in calling python function from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am making a code in Jupyter notebook using pandas, python, and javascript. 
I want to monitor the prices of products, here let's say the products' numbers as "1234" and "5678". 
 This table is renewed every 5 seconds, then new prices are appended and the links to buy them are attached on the bottom of the table.
In addition, I also want to display together the click counter(df_cnt), i.e. the number you clicked the links in the pandas table so far during the cell in the for loop running (#In[7] shown below). 
The clickable link in pandas table calls javascript function add(var1) #In[2] and then this add(var1) executes python function add_func(x) #In[4], which increments click counts for each product.

**Problem**

The problem is that the displayed counter(df_cnt) in #In[7] is not updated even if I clicked the links during the cell is running in #In[7], while after the for loop is finished, the counter (df_cnt) is updated correctly in the next cell (#In[8] shown below).

**What I tried**

I tried to change the command in the javascript from

```
kernel.execute( "df_cnt=add_func("+ var1 + ")") ;
```

to

```
kernel.execute( "df_cnt["+ var1 + "] += 1") ;
```

but the result was the same.

How can I dynamically update the pandas table df_cnt in in #In[7]? I appreciate any comments or suggestions.

**Code**

```
# In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import copy
from random import randint 
from time import sleep
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

%%html
# In[2]:
<script>
function add(var1) {
        var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
        kernel.execute( "df_cnt=add_func("+ var1 + ")") ;  
        alert(var1 + " is clicked." ) ; 
    };
</script>

# In[3]:
def row_wise_clickable_add(val):
    return f'<a  onclick="add(%s)" target="_blank">%s</a>'%(val,val)

# In[4]:
def add_func(x):
    global df_cnt
    df_cnt[x] +=1
    return df_cnt

# In[5]:
df_cnt=pd.DataFrame([[0,0]],columns=[1234,5678])  # pandas table for click counter
df=pd.DataFrame([[0,0 ]],columns=[1234,5678]  ) # pandas table for price monitoring
```

This is the function for monitoring.

```
# In[6]:
def monitor():
    global df,df_cnt
    sleep(5)
    df_new=pd.DataFrame(data=[[int(randint(1,10)) for _ in range(2) ]],columns=[1234,5678])
    df=df.append(df_new,sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    df2=df.copy()
    df_tmp=pd.DataFrame([df2.columns.tolist()],columns=df2.columns)
    df2=df2.append(df_tmp.astype(int).rename(index={df_tmp.index[-1]: 'buy'}))
    s=df2.style.format(row_wise_clickable_add, subset=pd.IndexSlice[ df2.index[-1], df2.columns.tolist()[0:]])
    clear_output()
    return s
```

After definition of functions, and initialization of pandas tables, main part starts.

```
# In[7]:
for k in range(7): 
    s=monitor()
    print("Price monitor:")
    display(s)
    print("Click counter: ")
    display(df_cnt) # not updated while running this cell...
```

After finished the cell above, pandas table for click counter is updated,
but not within the for loop shown above...

```
# In[8]:
df_cnt
```